# Saving data inside and outside a form into a database

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm learning to code with Django. So I have a form that displays quizzes and a JavaScript file that computes these quizzes.
The quizzes are displayed in a `<form>`, and I have other details like course still displayed on the form.
To the best of my knowledge, POST only takes data within the form. What if I have the score outside the form, how do I go about it?

This is what I've done already:

The JavaScript that computes the results:

```
function submitAnswers(answers) {

var total = answers.length;
var score = 0;
var choice = []

//new dynamic method 1
for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) {

    choice[i] = document.forms["quizForm"]["q" + i].value;
}


for (i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
    if (choice[i] == null || choice[i] == '') {
        alert('You skipped question ' + i);
        return false;
    }
}


// new dynamic method for checking answer
for (i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
    if (choice[i] == answers[i - 1]) {
        score++;
    }
}

//Display Result
var results = document.getElementById('results');
results.innerHTML = "<h3>You scored <span>" + score + "</span> out of <span>" + total + "</span></h3>"
alert("You scored " + score + " out of " + total);

var scoreOnly = document.getElementById('scoreOnly');
scoreOnly.innerHTML = score;

document.getElementById('btnSubmit').style.display = 'none';

return false;
}
```

The HTML that carries the questions, answers, course, as Wells as the score:

```
//Gets its value after JavaScript has finished computing.
<div class="text-blue text-darken-3" id="results"></div>
//This div scores only the score. No additional information.
                    <div class="text-blue text-darken-3" id="scoreOnly" name="scoreOnly" hidden></div>
                    <hr>
                    <form method="POST" name="quizForm" action="/quizzer/"
                        onsubmit="return submitAnswers(answers = [{% for q in questn %}'{{ q.answer }}',{% endfor %}])">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div name="canditate">{{user.email}}</div>
                        {% for q in questn %}
                       <div name="course">{{q.course}}</div>
                        <h5> {{ q.question|safe }} </h5>
                        <p><label><input class="with-gap" name="q{{ q.id }}" type="radio" value="a" /><span
                                    class="blue-text text-darken-2"> {{ q.option_a|safe }}</span></label></p>
                        <p><label><input class="with-gap" name="q{{ q.id }}" type="radio" value="b" /><span
                                    class="blue-text text-darken-2"> {{ q.option_b|safe }}</span></label></p>
                        <p><label><input class="with-gap" name="q{{ q.id }}" type="radio" value="c" /><span
                                    class="blue-text text-darken-2"> {{ q.option_c|safe }}</span></label></p>
                        <br>
                        <hr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <br>
                        <center><button class="btn blue darken-3" type="submit" id="btnSubmit">SUBMIT</button></center>
                    </form>
```

The code I tried:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        context = {}
        questn = Questions.objects.all()
        context['title'] = 'Exams'
        context['questn'] = questn
        return render(request, "quizzer/index.html", context)

    if request.method == "POST":
        # print(request.POST)
        course = request.POST["course"]
        scoreResult = request.POST["scoreOnly"]

        theScores = ExamScores(course=course, scoreResult=scoreResult)
        theScores.save()
        return render(request, "quizzer/index.html", context)
```

What I want is a way to post both items outside and inside the `<form>` into the database.

Comment: I don't understand why you're putting stuff outside the form.

Comment: I tried it within the form, it still didn't work for me. Could you please help me have a look?

Comment: Typically, instead of calculating a quiz score on the client, and then sending that score and course to the server, you'd send the client's **answers** to the server ("never trust the client") and then the server could compute the score, save it, and return a response to the client. Your JavaScript is essentially validating that all answers were answered, which you could do simply by making all of your `input` fields `required`.

Comment: If you're committed to this approach, you need to make hidden input fields named `course` and `scoreOnly` that are inside of your `<form>` tag. Set their values in your `submitAnswers` function, as you do with your scoreOnly `div` when you display the results to the user. The `div` contents do not get submitted with a form, which is likely why you're not seeing anything in `request.POST["course"]` or `request.POST["scoreOnly"]` variables on the server.

Comment: You're correct. I think the post isnt sending as at the time I hit the submit button. While I try finding a way on my own, could you please help me out with a better approach in codes? Or edit mine please?

Answer (score 0):

You have a two kind of solution.

first: making post requst with [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

second: it is possible to add form attribute to inputs that placed outside of form. You can get it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp).

But: I hope you need to calculate the scores of quizzes in server side. Because in terms of security and correct logical approach.